# Delete option for user if he is the owner of the perticular property

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I want to show delete option for a user if he has created perticular exhibit. I am getting a current user id from getCurrentUser service and i am getting an array of exhibits in which thre is a field "userId".

I am trying to match id of the current user and userId from Exhibits array in such a way that if there is a match, then only user will get delete option for perticular exhibit but I am unable to do it in proper way.

Below is my code:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentUser();
    this.getIsSupervisor();
    this.spinnerService.show();
    let allRoutesOption = Route.emptyRoute();
    allRoutesOption.title = 'ALL';
    this.routes = [allRoutesOption];

    this.getAllExhibits();

    this.routeService.getAllRoutes(1, 100)
      .then(
        data => this.routes = this.routes.concat(data.items)
      ).catch(
        error => console.error(error)
      );

    this.getPage(1);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.spinnerService.hide();
  }

  getIsSupervisor() {
    this.supervisorGuard.isSupervisor().then(
      (response: boolean) => {
        this.isSupervisor = response;
      });
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    this.userService.getCurrent()
      .then(
        (response) => {
          this.currentUserId = response.id;
          this.exhibitService.getAllExhibits(1, this.maxNumberOfMarkers)
            .then(
              (data) => {
                this.allExhibits = data.items;
                for (let exhibit of this.allExhibits) {
                  this.exhibitsUserIds.push(exhibit.userId);
                    if (this.exhibitsUserIds !== this.currentUserId) {
                      this.canDelete = false;
                    } else {
                      this.canDelete = true;
                    }
                }
              }
            );
        }
      );
  }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Html:

```
----------------------------------------
  <md-nav-list>
    <md-list-item [routerLink]="['/mobile-content/exhibits/view', exhibit.id]" ng-blur="true" *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits | paginate: { id: 'server',
                                                                itemsPerPage: exhibitsPerPage,
                                                                currentPage: currentPage,
                                                                totalItems: totalItems }">
      <img md-list-avatar *ngIf="previewsLoaded && previews.has(exhibit.id); else exhibitIcon" [src]="previews.get(exhibit.id)"
        alt="{{ 'image preview' | translate }}" [ngStyle]="{'width.px': 48, 'height.px': 48}">
      <ng-template #exhibitIcon>
        <md-icon md-list-icon class="type-icon" [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px': 40, 'height.px': 40, 'width.px': 40}">place</md-icon>
      </ng-template>
      <h2 md-line>{{ exhibit.name }} ({{ exhibit.status | translate }})
        <hip-star-rating class="fix-position" *ngIf="exhibit.ratings" [rating]='exhibit.ratings' [exhibitId]='exhibit.id'></hip-star-rating>
      </h2>
      <p md-line>{{ exhibit.description }}</p>
      <p md-line>
        <span class="latitude">{{ exhibit.latitude }}</span>,
        <span class="longitude">{{ exhibit.longitude }}</span>
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="exhibit.tags.length > 0" md-line>
        <span *ngFor="let tag of exhibit.tags" class="tag-name">{{ tag }}</span>
      </p>

      <button md-icon-button click-stop-propagation color="primary" [routerLink]="['/mobile-content/exhibits/edit', exhibit.id]"
        title="{{ 'edit' | translate }}">
        <md-icon>{{ !inDeletedPage ? 'edit' : 'remove_red_eye'}}</md-icon>
      </button>
      <div *ngIf="canDelete">
        <button md-icon-button click-stop-propagation color="warn" (click)="deleteExhibit(exhibit)" *ngIf="!exhibit.used && !inDeletedPage"
          title="{{ 'delete' | translate }}">
          <md-icon>delete_forever</md-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
----------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Angular myself but maybe I can still help. I am noticing a couple things that may be causing issues.

## Firstly

When you are iterating across `this.allExhibits`, I noticed that the `this.canDelete` is just one value that you keep reassigning after each iteration. By the end it only represents the 'deleteability' of only the last exhibit.

Perhaps you can create some sort of object or array to map against the for..of iteration of `this.allExhibits`. That way you can store each resolved value of `this.canDelete` without overwriting it on each iteration.

#### example.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  currentUser:object = {
    name: 'User A',
    id: 'A'
  };

  exhibits:object[] = [
    {
      title: 'Exhibit A',
      id: 'A'
    },
    {
      title: 'Exhibit B',
      id: 'B'
    },
    {
      title: 'Exhibit C',
      id: 'C'
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  deleteExhibit(index) {
    this.exhibits = this.exhibits.filter((_, i) => i != index);
  }
}
```

#### example.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let exhibit of exhibits; let i=index">
  <h3>{{exhibit.title}}</h3>
  <button *ngIf="exhibit.id == currUser.id" (click)="deleteExhibit(i)">DELETE</button>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

## Secondly

I presume the `getCurrentUser()` is something that happens as the component instantiates. In that case, the *ngIf must await the resolved value of `this.canDelete` before it can either display or hide the delete button.

Since `getCurrentUser()` appears to resolve sometime after the component's initial rendering of the view, it maybe be possible that setting the value of `this.canDelete` is not triggering Angular's change detection.

Perhaps try `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after you resolve the final value of `this.canDelete`. ChangeDetectorRef is importable from `@angular/core` and instantiable in the component's constructor: `constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}`.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @John..I am trying to do as u said, but still I am unable to do that. I stored userIds from all exhibits and then trying to match the condition and when i put it in HTML, delete option has gone for all exhibits. I have only one exhibit which has been created by current user and for that exhibit only, i want delete option. Is it possible to do this some other way? Thanks for you suggestion..

Comment: @RuchirNaphade I included an example in my answer. I omitted the need for a `this.canDelete` by instead comparing between `exhibit.id` and `currentUser.id` directly in the html. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: John is right when you have to consider multiple behavior for sub parts of a component then you can not use only one variable. You must create an array of objects that will contains the delete state for each case. Like so : allmycase = [{ id: "A, title: "AAA", delete: false }, {}...]...